# Oracle NVARCHAR2(Max) using nhibernate 2.1

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Here is my problem: I have Oracle Database 10g and I use nhibernete 2.1 for the mapping. Now when I create a table in oracle My table's hbm.xml file is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="AssembleName" namespace="NamesapceName" >
<class name="ClassName" table="TableName" schema="ScheamName"
     dynamic-update="true"  dynamic-insert="true"  select-before-update="true">
<id name="Id" column="id" type="integer" unsaved-value="0">
  <generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
<property name="Name" column="name" type="StringClob" length="100000" not-null="true" />
  </class>
```

and if I give the length of property greater than 4000 it created in this format

```
create table TableName (
    id NUMBER(10,0) not null,
   name NCLOB not null, 
   primary key (id)
)
```

and when I fetch the table item using my own function
 I am encountering Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB problem
But When I set the property like

```
<property name="Name" column="name" type="string" length="2000" not-null="true" />
```

it created in this format

```
create table TableName (
    id NUMBER(10,0) not null,
   name NVARCHAR(2000) not null, 
   primary key (id)
)
```

and my function for fetching data was working fine. But I need a table that has string length > 4000 without Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB

Comment: In Oracle you cannot define a (N)VARCHAR column with more than 4000 bytes. You have to use CLOB or NCLOB for larger values. Please show us the code for your "*own function*" that access the column.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just this?

```
<property name="Name" length="10000" not-null="true" />
```

I'm using SQL Server and I don't need to specify a type in such a case.